# Clear Recent file history

Tags: interface, blend-files

I’ve moved a lot of files and blender doesn’t know the path for them now. Is there anyway to clear the recent list so I won’t get bothered by it saying file path is missing?

Comment: Depending on which OS you are using, go to the folder where Blender stores your startup .blend file. In that folder there is a recent-files.txt file. You can edit, or delete that file as you like.

Comment: @curious_1 thanks. Found it in Appdata/Roaming/BlenderFoundation/Blender/3.6/config